# Does the build folder in android studio project fix missing or wrong files on rebuild?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, rebuild

I am backing up android studio projects in google drive and I found that the /app/build folder contains thousands of files, and worse yet, they are probably updated each time I run the app, so google drive ends up confused and tired.
So can I just ignore that specific folder from syncing altogether?

I am syncing because I sometimes work on a PC and sometimes on a laptop.
If I skip that folder and rebuild when I switch between PC and laptop, will this practice affect my code?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer is no.**

Actually more than 60% of size for project is because of build. Every time you import it will build from beginnning just replace the entire data. So never worry about build folder. you can build later with some of the build tools

Comment: So I can safely sync other files except build folder and expect the folder to build (or work correctly) at run time?